# проблема с настройкой Continious Integration (Team City)

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, msbuild

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

unmet requirement: MSBuildTools14.0_x86_Path exists

- Последняя версия ТимСити ( 2017.1.1 (build 46654) )
- Visual Studio 2015
- стоит последний WebDeploy
- стоят Microsoft Build Tools 2015 и 2013 уже
- агент тим сити перезагружал. Как и компьютер. Как и сам тим сити переустанавливал несколько раз. (в том числе сегодня скачанный, так что гарантированно последний)
- нужная папка c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\ существует
- список установленных .Net
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Настройки агента дефолтные:
  ....

  ```
  serverUrl=http\://localhost\:85

  systemDir=C\:\\Program Files\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\system
  env.TEAMCITY_JRE=C\:\\Program Files\\TeamCity\\jre
  name=Lola
  tempDir=C\:\\Program Files\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\temp
  workDir=C\:\\Program Files\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\work
  ownPort=9090

  authorizationToken=674a8681634ae16c80dd9d6da6c50375
  ```

Есть идеи?

Comment: на агенте  MSBuild установлена отдельно или как часть VS ?

Comment: рекоменую ознакомиться со [статьей](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206843275-Unmet-requirements-MSBuildTools12-0-x86-Path-exists)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor родная выдавала ту же ошибку. Но ставил отдельно. Статью уже видел. =(

Comment: Попробуй отключить это условие и посмотреть, на каком месте всё грохнется.

Comment: Так это первое условие -- билд проэкта. Да, можно сказать, и единственное. Отключать нету смысла.

Comment: А я бы всё равно отключил.

Comment: в самом проэкте пишет что компатибл agent http://prntscr.com/f8jifd но если пробовать джобу запустить, говорит что нету компатибл агентов http://prntscr.com/f8jiyr . Но это если именно удалить все степы. Если задисейблить -- та же самая ошибка что и в самой шапке.

Comment: @Andrew приложите настройти Build Step, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  Похоже что это какая-то внешняя проблема все равно, которая устранится просто после перестановки винды. На втором компе все ок практически со старта. Так что проще фотрточку переставить и на том все) Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опытным путем было выявлено что проще переставить винду, чем решить даную проблему по-человечески. Если кто столкнется с проблемой и все перечисленные выше пункты не помогут -- переставляйте винду и гори оно все синим пламенем :)

Проще и быстрее.